# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str in rasa training

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

Im getting this error while training the file config.yml file .Need Help

Comment: Can you please add the error description? Also the Rasa forum (https://forum.rasa.com) might be of help ins this case.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to add the model name to your config.yml file:

```
  - name: SpacyNLP
     model: en_core_web_md     //<<<
```

Comment: Documentation that states this is [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/changelog/#features-3). Required since  rasa `(2.5.0 - 2021-04-12)`